# Python Selenium Upload Button

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to upload file, but why isn't my code passing the file to the website
when it should?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, os



driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/User/Downloads/drivers/geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https://gofile.io/")

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[5]/button[2]").send_keys("C:\\Downloads\\audio.mp3")
```

Comment: can you share the error msg

Comment: you want to send keys to the <input> tag of type "file".  (This sets the value attribute.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload file you should send keys to the hidden `input` element with `type=file`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/User/Downloads/drivers/geckodriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']"))).send_keys("C:\\Downloads\\audio.mp3")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Upload Audio File']"))).click()
```